# Use Python to change datasource from a feature class to a view built on the feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, python-2.7

I'm trying to replace the datasource for all of the layers in my map document using Python but I keep running into an error.  Right now, all of the layers point to a feature class called GISDB.DBO.TESTFEATURECLASS and I want them to point to a view that I built using the sdetable -o createview command.  It has both the object id and geometry columns from the original feature class.  It shows up in ArcCatalog with the same icon as a feature class and I can add it as a layer in ArcMap.

> Runtime error <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Layer: Unexpected error

```
mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
workspace_path = r'Database Connections\TestGIS.sde'
workspace_type = "SDE_WORKSPACE"
dataset_name = r'GISDB.DBO.TESTFEATURECLASS_VIEW'
for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc):
    layer.replaceDataSource(workspace_path, workspace_type, dataset_name)
```

How can I determine which property is causing the error?

Comment: I had some troubles with .replaceDataSource when doing layer repointing in an mxd with arcpy.  I think some of the problem was updating the mxd and saving it.  You may be repathing it but then you don't save it.  I'll try to find some code that ended up working for me.

Comment: arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(p1,p2,p3,false) ...may also help.  p1 is parameter 1.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29185/replace-data-source-of-layer-in-modelbuilder/29294#29294, I was getting the same error as you. Turns out I had to add mxd.save() at the end to ensure the data source was replaced.

Comment: @Arabella I ran into the save error when I replaced the layer workspaces from a Python window in ArcCatalog. I think the problem there was that I hadn't allowed the mxd file to be closed because closing all instances of ArcCatalog and ArcMap and starting fresh allowed me to make my changes and save them.

Comment: @Justin updateLayer would work but I don't want to replace the symbology.  I think the underlying problem is that the string I'm using for either the workspace or the datasetName is wrong but I don't know where to find the correct string.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are running this from the Python window of ArcMap.

Consequently, I would expect a little more to the error message.

Perhaps try including the following as the fifth line in your code snippet to see if that sheds more light:

```
print arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc)
```

It may help to determine whether it is your first or a particular layer that is throwing the error.